# what's the difference between this question and stackoverflow?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow

what's the difference between this question and stackoverflow?

Specifically should I ask my HTML/CSS questions here or at stackoverflow?

Comment: additionally see my answer at http://meta.webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/470/web-development-question-migrated-to-stackoverflow/472#472

Answer (score 5):

If it is coding question it should be at StackOverflow. If it's a theory question, it belongs here.

If you're still not sure update your question with a summary of the question you wish to ask and we'll point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Questions about bugs/issues or how to do something general in HTML and CSS belong on Stackoverflow.com.  Questions that are in html and css that deal with SEO or managing a website (like how to do redirects, load balancing, static image servers, etc) are good questions for Webmasters.  If you are unsure explain what you want to ask hear and we will let you know.